# Why the compiler is unable to load the library name dbexpint.dll?

Tags: delphi, dll, firebird, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm a new user o Delphi 10.2 Tokyo (trial version) when I compile the program source code this error message appears:

***Unable to load dbexpint.dll (ErrorCode 126). It may be missing from the system path.***

This code should access a Firebird database, I have Firebird Client 3.0 installed on my machine. inside the installation folder I have the DLLs:

- FBCLIENT.DLL
- MSVCP100.DLL
- MSVCR100.DLL

Below is part of the source code.

```
unit uDataModule;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DBXCommon, DB, DBClient, SimpleDS, SqlExpr, FMTBcd,
  ADODB, Data.DBXInterBase, Data.DBXOracle;

...

procedure TDM.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  strPath: String;
begin
  //Conex?o Firebird SPIRIDON
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Clear;
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['DatabaseServer'] := 'Interbase';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['Database']       := 'XXXXXXXXXX:f:\dados\database\XXXXXXXXXXXX.FDB';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['SQLDialect']     := '3';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['DriverName']     := 'Interbase';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['VendorLib']      := 'gds32.dll';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['User_Name']      := 'XXXXXXXX';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['Password']       := 'XXXXXXXX';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['LibraryName']    := 'dbexpint.dll';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['GetDriverFunc']  := 
 'getSQLDriverINTERBASE';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Connected:= True;
```

- I tried to download the DLL and put it in the system32 and wow64 folders, but it was not effective.
- I tried changing the reference from the Library name line to dbxint.dll, but the following error appears:

*DBX Error: Driver could not be properly initialized. Client library may be missing, not installed properly, of the wrong version, or the driver may be missing from the system path.*

I don't know what's wrong and how I can solve it. Please, can you guys help me?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question last week? Also, don't ever put DLLs into the system directories.

Comment: What you need to do is learn how to link to a database using the tools you have. Do t take an old project, with little to no knowledge and hope to make it work by trial and error. Start with an empty project and work through the official tutorials and documentation. Novices often have a mistaken belief that they can solve hard problems without spending the time it requires to gain knowledge. You asking here because you want help from experts. The experts didn't become experts by trial and error. They read and researched and invested time. You must do so too.

Comment: Here is DBX internal registering unit for Firebird for Delphi XE2, based (if I remember) upon Andreas Hausladen blog post - https://github.com/the-Arioch/XE2fixes - I think it can be used for XE10 with minor changes or maybe even verbatim

Answer (score 2):

`dbexpint.dll` is the dbExpress Interbase driver for (old) Delphi versions from [Delphi 6 to Delphi 2005](http://www.drbob42.com/examine/examin91.htm). It could also be used to connect with Firebird databases, while newer Delphi versions use separate drivers for each one.

This driver is **not** compatible with Delphi versions 2006 and later. Instead, Delphi 10.2 now uses `dbxint.dll` for [Interbase](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/interbase), and `dbxfb.dll` for [Firebird](https://firebirdsql.org).

The params of `dbxfb.dll` are similar to that of `dbexpint.dll`.

If you create a new form, drop a [TSQLConnection](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection) on it and select `FBConnection` as the value of the [`ConnectionName`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.ConnectionName) property, then the [`Driver`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.DriverName) property will automatically be assigned with the needed value `Firebird`, and the [`Params`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLConnection.Params) property will also be populated with suitable values:

```
object SQLConnection1: TSQLConnection
  ConnectionName = 'FBConnection'
  DriverName = 'Firebird'
  Params.Strings = (
    'DriverName=Firebird'
    'Database=database.fdb'
    'RoleName=RoleName'
    'User_Name=sysdba'
    'Password=masterkey'
    'ServerCharSet='
    'SQLDialect=3'
    'ErrorResourceFile='
    'LocaleCode=0000'
    'BlobSize=-1'
    'CommitRetain=False'
    'WaitOnLocks=True'
    'IsolationLevel=ReadCommitted'
    'Trim Char=False')
  Left = 312
  Top = 172
end
```

**Note:** As mentioned by ***@DavidHeffernan*** in the comments, don't put DLLs into system directories. Better put it in the same folder as your exe file.

Comment: "It can" - it COULD but can no more :-D as a person, who transitioned our project form D2006 to DXE2 I can confirm :-) Except that in older Delphi releases it was named according to DBX version, like dbxint30.dll for Delphi 2006

Comment: @Arioch'The. Thanks, I've clarified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help.

I found a way to fix the error:

Actually the dbexpint.dll driver only worked on the older versions of Delphi. The current driver is dbxfb.dll for connections to the Firebird database.

Firstly I changed the lines of code as below.

```
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Clear;
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['DatabaseServer'] := 'Firebird';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['Database']       := 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx:f:\dados\database\xxxxxxxxxx.FDB';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['SQLDialect']     := '3';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['DriverName']     := 'Firebird';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['VendorLib']      := 'fbclient.dll';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['User_Name']      := 'SYSDBA';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['Password']       := 'xxxxxxx';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['LibraryName']    := 'dbxfb.dll';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Params.Values['GetDriverFunc']  := 'getSQLDriverINTERBASE';
  SQLSpiridonConnection.Connected:= True;
```

After that I inserted these dlls into the Firebird installation folder.

- borlndmm.dll
- dbxfb.dll
- midas.dll
- fbclient.dll **this dll is already installed in the folder**

The other dlls are inside the delphi installation folder.

Ex: C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Embarcadero \ Studio \ 19.0 \ bin

OBS: @DavidHeffernan Yes I did already asked this question, thanks for your  comment

Comment: Are you *sure* you need Midas.Dll?  It is primarily to support TClientDataSet.  Do you use TCDS?

Comment: I don't know if it's really necessary. Could you please explain to me what this dll is for? What about the TCDS class?

Comment: Midas.Dll implements the functionality of a specialised dataset which is surfaced in Delphi as TClientDataSet (TCDS for short) and also TSimpleDataSet. They are both described in the online help. If your app does not use either of these components, you do not need Midas.Dll. Be aware that Delphi's dbExpress *does* use TSimpleDataSet.  As @DavidHeffernan said, you need to work through the official documentation and tutorials - there is no short-cut to getting familiar with db-access or anything else in Delphi.